# Creating Symfony project from windows 10 error?

Tags: php, json, symfony, composer-php

Currently I have downloaded Symfony 3.0 
[image]

and configured invironment variables and installed Composer and checked composer.json inside c:\xampp\htdocs\symfony it includes the downloaded version of symfony.

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0"
    },
```

I have two problems:
1. I have seen the congradualtin screen of symfony and I can't to access the windows of symfony
2. When I try to create the first project using :

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony>composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project "3.0.*" --stability=dev
```

and also tried as:

```
C:\>composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "3.0.*"
```

I have got the following error:

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No connection could
  be made because the target machine actively refused it.


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Any one try to solve the problem. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Your PC is probably behind a proxy. Try running `composer diagnose` to get some more information. If you are behind a proxy, set the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable, see https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1991#issuecomment-21842401 for more information.